# Problems with render fonts of a .svg file using Overleaf

Tags: fonts, svg, rendering

I already seen some questions about this but I can't figure a solution. My problem is that when I insert a .svg file it not render like in Mozilla or GIMP.

In Overleaf looks like this:
[image]

And in Mozilla for example (this is the way that I want):
[image]

The fonts in the svg are Times New Roman and cmmi10.ttf and I'm compiling with pdfLaTeX in Overleaf with this initial code: (after the edit I added more for the comments)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmgraph}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\graphicspath{ {Figurer/} }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{svg} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \includesvg[]{18.svg}
    \caption{$\mathcal{R}_n$}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false]{18.svg}
    \caption{$\mathcal{R}_n$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:
[image]

[image]

And for last can get the original svg file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2allGwR0D18nJGAlWpbe8zuhTYjT1tu/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for all in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The error you show is about a `\texttheta` which is not defined  and that you are using in a tabular --- so nothing to do with the `svg` files (there could be an error there, too, but it's impossible to say with this code... (BTW, `\texttheta` is a TIPA command --- are you doing something linguistic-based?)

Comment: @Rmano I don't really know how to answer, I use the theta from Times New Roman.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no time to debug a whole project. Do your part and try to reduce the problem to a short snippet --- It will be useful for you too. And never use `\\\` to end a paragraph.

Comment: Ok, thank you any way and for the advice.

Comment: The problem is not the theta in the graphics, is the theta you have in the tabulars that is not set up for pdflatex. Try to use `$\theta$` instead. And, by the way, the font you use in your LaTeX code has no special significance. I suggest you to have a walk around here: https://www.learnlatex.org/

Comment: BTW, sharing that (overleaf) link here means that anybody can edit, delete, copy or do whatever thing to your document. I suggest you to delete that comment as soon as possible.

Comment: @Rmano really thank you again, I will see that for sure.

Comment: What about converting your SVG-file to TikZ [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) first and using the TikZ picture instead. So the currently used font in your document will be used within the picture too.

Comment: @susisstrolch thank you for the answer, later I will try that.